# close child popup pages on logout / closing the parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to close all child windows on closing/logout of Main page/window .I am using c# for button click event.
On Logout button click event of main page I need to close all other child popups.
My popup page name is dmssview.aspx and logout button click code behind below

```
protected void BLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["UserAuthentication"] = null;
  Response.Redirect("~/SM_Login.aspx");
}
```

Please help me for closing popup pages

Answer (score 0):

write the code in the log out button's click event

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {        
            for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count-1 ; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name != "Menu")
                    Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
            }



     }
```